# Negative Binomial Distributing finding X

Tags: binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

The number of injuries at a college football game has the following probability distribution:

Probability 0.14 0.33 0.23 0.17 0.09 0.04
Number of injuries 0 1 2 3 4 5

The coach must file a report whenever there is more than one injury in any game.

Calculate the expected number of football games to be played before the first game in which there are at least four injuries.

Comment: Is it $36$ games to be played

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: It is sort of negative binomial, but a special case of it called the geometric distribution.  Recall that if $X$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p$ then $E(X)=1/p$.

Comment: So you just take my hint to your first question and open new question without even trying to think about it.

Comment: so would the answer be .87/.13 = 6.69?

Comment: "The coach must file a report whenever there is more than one injury in any game" - what relevance does that have to the question at hand???

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}n\cdot(1-0.09-0.04)^n\cdot(0.09+0.04)=6.69231$$

Comment: How would you solve this?

Comment: @user3777772: Solve what?

Comment: what is n? 20???

Comment: @user3777772: $n$ is a variable which goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Then how did you solve for your answer

Comment: @user3777772: I split into **disjoint** events, and summed up the product of each event (number of days) by the probability of that event.